# Google app engine regular expression

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I'm working on a Google appengine project and I've encountered a quandary.  The following should (if the regex's are normal) redirect everything which does not contain the word "test" to the MainPage class, and the rest to the TestPage class.

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [
                                        ('[^(test)]*', MainPage),
                                        ('.+', TestPage)
                                     ],
                                     debug=True)
```

Instead, I find that the regular expression is being interpreted:

```
('[^tes]*', MainPage)
```

This means that anything which includes a t, e, or s will NOT direct to MainPage (in this case, it will direct to TestPage).  Obviously, the workaround is to re-write the TestPage regex, but I don't want to have to make a work around.  This *should* work without being re-written.

Am I missing some library somewhere?  Is this a configuration issue?  I have far less issue with calling a function or setting a property before running `run_wsgi_app`, but this looks inconsistent as is.

---

#### UPDATE

It turns out that the culprit was two things.  First it was a mistake on my part in the syntax (Mea culpa).  Second, the tool I had used to confirm the regular expression said that the expression would not match "test " but it would match "t est ".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it's being interpreted as identical to any rearrangement of the characters aside from the leading caret within the square brackets, such as `[^est()]`. Standard regular expression syntax includes no straightforward way to specify the complement of the language matched by a particular regex.

In this case, you don't need to worry about that. Follow Erik Noren's advice and change the order of the matching expressions like so:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [
                                        ('test', TestPage)
                                        ('.+', MainPage),
                                     ],
                                     debug=True)
```

This straightforwardly accomplishes the same result.

Comment: It looks like a combination of issues.  I happened to be using a RegEx parser for something else which was behaving as I expected it to (as described above) and (obviously) I thought that my syntax was correct (the thought: since it worked in that alternate environment, why wouldn't it here?).

Answer (score 3):

Why not just invert it? Instead of checking for [not 'test'] the check for test is simpler. Route that match to TestPage and the rest to MainPage.

The difference of (not working):

```
'[^(test)]*'
```

and

```
'test'
```

Unless I'm completely mistaken.

Comment: Oh, I knew how to reverse it, but I didn't like that I had to.

Answer (score 3):

The square-bracket notation in regex is a set of characters, and parens have no special meaning within them.  So `[^(test)]` matches any character other than 't', 'e', 's', '(', or ')'

Comment: Just to supplement Ned's answer, here is a link to the docs that explain this: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html